# filter data from firebase in flutter with 2 variables and 2 firebase fields

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, filter

I'm new in Flutter, i'm trying to get the data from Firestore DB and show it as a ListTile.
But trying to filter it with 2 variables.
i'm trying to make the imagens when the selectedDisciplina(from the code) and disciplina(from firebase) is equal and when selectedModulos(from the code) is equal to modulo(from firebase).
if this is true it will show the image from the url in the firebase
[image: the firebase]

i tried this but this is just for the selectedDisciplina and disciplina (i'm trying to make for both of them.

```
final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map<String, Object?>;
    final selectedModulo = routeArgs['idModulo'].toString();
    final selectedDisciplina = routeArgs['idDisc'].toString();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Resumos'),
      ),
      // streamBuilder é usado para auto se construir de acordo com o snapshot(data recebida da base de dados)
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _firebaseFirestore.snapshots().asBroadcastStream(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          // se o snapshot for null mostra o simbolo de loading
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Something went wrong"),
            );
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              // simbolo de loding
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            if (snapshot.data!.docs
                .where((QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>
                        element) => // campo da firestore
                    element['disciplina']
                        // como o campo é int tem que se passar para string
                        .toString()
                        .toLowerCase()
                        // onde (where) tiver (contains) a query igual ao que está nas disciplina
                        .contains(selectedDisciplina.toString()))
                .isEmpty) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Por aqui está muito lento, carrega no botão e publica um resumo.',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView(
                children: [
                  // os ... permite nos adicinar varios widgets
                  // onde o campo da firestore disciplina for igual ao que está no query ele cria um mapa
                  ...snapshot.data!.docs
                      .where((QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>
                              element) => // campo da firestore
                          element['disciplina']
                              // como o campo é int tem que se passar para string
                              .toString()
                              .toLowerCase()
                              // onde (where) tiver (contains) a query igual ao que está nas disciplina
                              .contains(selectedDisciplina.toString()))
                      .map(
                    (QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> data) {
                      // guarda na variavel disciplina o que esta na firestore
                      final String descricao = data.get('descricao');
                      // guarda na variavel image o que esta na firestore
                      final _image = data['url'];
                      // depois cria um ListTile em relação á data dada em cima
                      return ListTile(
                        onTap: () {
                          //_downloadImage(_image, descricao);
                          print(
                              'disciplina: $selectedDisciplina modulo: $selectedModulo');
                          // fazer o downLoad
                        },
                        // mostra a imagem
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_image),
                        ),

                        // mostra a disciplina
                        title: Text(
                          descricao.toString(),
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            }
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // quando o botao é precionado vai para o UploadScreen
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(UploadResumoScreen.routeName);
        },
        //cor do background
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 28, 209, 216),
        // tipo do icon
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        // cor do icon
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add modulo check condition with && operator

1.

```
if (snapshot.data!.docs
            .where((QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>
                    element) => // campo da firestore
                element['disciplina']
                    // como o campo é int tem que se passar para string
                    .toString()
                    .toLowerCase()
                    // onde (where) tiver (contains) a query igual ao que está nas disciplina
                    .contains(selectedDisciplina.toString()))
            .isEmpty && element['modulo']
                    // como o campo é int tem que se passar para string
                    .toString()
                    .toLowerCase()
                    // onde (where) tiver (contains) a query igual ao que está nas disciplina
                    .contains(selectedModulos.toString()))
            .isEmpty)
```

2. 

```
...snapshot.data!.docs
                  .where((QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>
                          element) => // campo da firestore
                      element['disciplina']
                          // como o campo é int tem que se passar para string
                          .toString()
                          .toLowerCase()
                          // onde (where) tiver (contains) a query igual ao que está nas disciplina
                          .contains(selectedDisciplina.toString()) && element['modulo']
                          // como o campo é int tem que se passar para string
                          .toString()
                          .toLowerCase()
                          // onde (where) tiver (contains) a query igual ao que está nas disciplina
                          .contains(selectedModulos.toString()))
```